# Regex to select the text between double wrapped braces jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

String = vegan ((International Vegetarian Union: Shelly - The First Celebrity Vegan January 5, 2011, Accessed 2022-06-22)) dying animals."((Shelley, Percy Bysshe. A Vindication of Natural Diet. Percy Bysshe Shelley. Kindle e-Book, A public domain book. Vegetarian Society, 1884. ISBN 1537113607, Kindle location 271)) He wrote a book,egetable diet is best suited to humans.((Ibid.))

I tried

```
jQuery('p').html(function(i, h) {
    return h.replace(/(\(.+\))/g, '<span class="titleEpisodeValue">$1</span>');
});
```

Fiddle to test. https://jsfiddle.net/wmz251nx/

It is wrapping the whole string than just the text inside the (( braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use the non greedy +? operator. Moreover, you may need to explicitely capture the group (with simple parenthesis) inside the (escaped) double parenthesis pattern.

```
jQuery('p').html(function(i, h) {
    return h.replace(/\(\((.+?)\)\)/g, '<span class="titleEpisodeValue">$1</span>');
});
```

Here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4qdLoacn/
Note: You can test and get explanation on regex much easier with https://regex101.com/

Comment: @Ali, did the response helped ?